# Postback request and ajax request in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Is the any way to find out that a request is a normal request (request such as postback operation or redirect or form submit) or an Ajax request?

I am using **JQuery** lib to send a request and call a **Web Method**

Comment: So how are you calling the Web Method except for the AJAX call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Web Forms and Update Panels here is what we use:

```
ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this);
return sm != null && sm.IsInAsyncPostBack;
```

More general method would be to check for the X-Requested-With header in the request.

```
Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest"
```

What is better for you depends on your scenario. Do you want to detect if the page is executing a partial update or you want to know if the browser requested it via XMLHttpRequest?

Another option when using JavaScript to make the AJAX call is to pass a query string parameter indicating that you are making an AJAX call.

Comment: thanks man , i works great,thanks again, you helped me,your answer is accepted now by me.good luck

Comment: Checking the X-Requested-With header should work but it is strange that your code is called with anything else but AJAX if you are calling it with JQuery.